# How to load web-animations-js polyfill in angular 5 without breaking ie9?

Tags: angular, internet-explorer-9, polyfills, web-animations

I have an Angular 6 app.

I would like to load Web Animations Js polyfill, but when its loaded IE9 displays an error and stops loading the App.

Is there any work around?

-I've tried to check the browser version using JS and then load the player using a require () call. This approach works well on Angular 5, but in Angular 6 require () its not available anymore.

-Another option is to wrap the pollyfill content in a function an call, it only when the browser is not IE9.

Any other idea that doesn't involve using server side browser detection?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi Miguel, did you find solution for this?